# The best way to handle the sqlite database create and read operations

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, google-maps-android-api-2

Althoung I have found a couple interesting posts about this topic, none of them is related to this kind of case or similar. I am developing an app which uses GoogleMaps API to show a map and I would like to have a database in which will be used to store all my points of interests (locations of e.g. police stations, hospitals, total of 478 entires) which will be placed on the map like markers aferwards.

These values will be inserted only once when the app is started for the first time, so I would guess that I do not need multiple threads or multiple instances of SQLiteHelpers in order to do this. Probably one of them should be enough to do the work, or not? Maybe it is important to mention that the users will not have a possibility to interact with the database.

I am having two activities so far, first is my InitActivity where I prepare some and check a couple of things important for the app and the second is my MainActivity. I would like to start with data insering in InitActivity as soon as the app starts but if it is possible not to wait for the whole process to ends in order to start the MainActivity, but to start it also when the data inserting starts. After the inserting finishs, I would like to call other method which will place the marker for each point of interest on the map. This method should be executed from the MainActivity. So I would need a background task which starts in one activity and informs other activity that the action is completed.

So, what could I use to carry out this kind of data inserting task and what would be the best way to do it (e.g AsyncTask - but is it possible to notify other activity that the process is completed)

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much trying to invent the wheel here, which is wasting the efforts as this thing is already invented for long time. You most likely would be happy with tools like [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) or other similar helpers.

> **Android SQLiteAssetHelper**
>
> An Android helper class to manage database creation and version
>   management using an application's raw asset files.
>
> This class provides developers with a simple way to ship their Android
>   app with an existing SQLite database (which may be pre-populated with
>   data) and to manage its initial creation and any upgrades required
>   with subsequent version releases.
>
> It is implemented as an extension to SQLiteOpenHelper, providing an
>   efficient way for ContentProvider implementations to defer opening and
>   upgrading the database until first use.
>
> **Rather than implementing the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods to
>   execute a bunch of SQL statements, developers simply include
>   appropriately named file assets in their project's assets directory.
>   These will include the initial SQLite database file for creation and
>   optionally any SQL upgrade scripts.**